MediaPerf is not registered: no key found at SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MediaPerf\Performance
While running the Echo Bot locally I am getting below error:
[SkypeBotsMediaPlatform][AppId:f05ea5ce-52a9-4efb-9dd4-e99a715c9570][KHADEERKI] MediaPerf is not registered: no key found at SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MediaPerf\Performance

I have used the code which is given in the repo and any steps and one change what I made is I have used cloudflare instead of ngrok.
As I was not able to run the EchoBot with ngrok to support http and tcp tunneling.
Below is the sample setting what I have made in launchsettings.json
{
"profiles": {
"EchoBot": {
"commandName": "Project",
"environmentVariables": {
"DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
"AppSettings__AadAppId": "f05ea5ce-52a9-4efb-9dd4-e99a715c9570",
"AppSettings__AadAppSecret": "mfL8Q~vJsmOk-.Jzu0QSqmZk7gAUdkI-6.37bJ",
"AppSettings__ServiceDnsName": "bot.techieguru-dev.cloud", //"bot.contoso.com",
"AppSettings__CertificateThumbprint": "b0736802816d508d3e40dd9f0db87c6915f953c3",
"AppSettings__BotCallingInternalPort": "9442",
"AppSettings__BotInstanceExternalPort": "443",
"AppSettings__BotInternalPort": "9441",
"AppSettings__MediaInstanceExternalPort": "80",
"AppSettings__MediaInternalPort": "8445",
"AppSettings__ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey": "InstrumentationKey",
"AppSettings__UseSpeechService": "false",
"AppSettings__SpeechConfigKey": "SpeechConfigKey",
"AppSettings__SpeechConfigRegion": "SpeechConfigRegion",
"AppSettings__BotLanguage": "en-US",
"AppSettings__UseLocalDevSettings": "true",
"AppSettings__MediaDnsName": "http-bot.techieguru-dev.cloud" //"tcp.contoso.com"
},
"dotnetRunMessages": true
}
}
}

Below are the tunnel settings in Cloudflare
Can you help in running the Echbot locally using free ngrok or cloudflare?

Please share the repo link of your code.
